# Rails created_at and update_at internal framework usage

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord

I´m changing these columns manually, extracting the time zone information of time values.

I was thinking if there are internal rules in Rails framework that use these two columns.

It´s safe to change them manually? I´m using this code for that:

```
module ActiveRecord
  class Base

    before_save :update_autocolumns

    def update_autocolumns

      if (!self.id) #inserting
        if (self.respond_to? :created_at)
          self.created_at = Time.now.ttz
        end
      end

      if (self.respond_to? :updated_at)
        self.updated_at = Time.now.ttz
      end
    end

  end
end
```

## update

this "ttz" method is used to extract time zone from time columns:

```
def ttz
  self.strftime('%a, %d %b %Y %H:%M:%S').to_time
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, there is, you can check the code in the [`Timestamps` module](https://github.com/rails/rails/blob/master/activerecord/lib/active_record/timestamp.rb). Your code is just redundant.

These attributes will be automatically updated on update.

```
def timestamp_attributes_for_update
  [:updated_at, :updated_on]
end
```

These attributes will be automatically updated on create.

```
def timestamp_attributes_for_create
  [:created_at, :created_on]
end
```

Here's the documentation.

```
  # = Active Record Timestamp
  #
  # Active Record automatically timestamps create and update operations if the
  # table has fields named <tt>created_at/created_on</tt> or
  # <tt>updated_at/updated_on</tt>.
  #
  # Timestamping can be turned off by setting:
  #
  #   config.active_record.record_timestamps = false
  #
  # Timestamps are in UTC by default but you can use the local timezone by setting:
  #
  #   config.active_record.default_timezone = :local
  #
  # == Time Zone aware attributes
  #
  # By default, ActiveRecord::Base keeps all the datetime columns time zone aware by executing following code.
  #
  #   config.active_record.time_zone_aware_attributes = true
  #
  # This feature can easily be turned off by assigning value <tt>false</tt> .
  #
  # If your attributes are time zone aware and you desire to skip time zone conversion to the current Time.zone
  # when reading certain attributes then you can do following:
  #
  #   class Topic < ActiveRecord::Base
  #     self.skip_time_zone_conversion_for_attributes = [:written_on]
  #   end
```